# How to write effective polymer element

Tags: polymer

I am writing a web site front-end by polymer, but I found that sometimes it response slowly, so can you give me any common tips to improve performance?

And I have some questions:

1. When show/hide some fields, which is better: `<... hidden?= "{{property}}">` vs `<template if = "{{property}}">;`?
2. Can I unbind some default events? For example, I have a block `<span>{{name}}</span>`, `this.name` won't change once set, can I unbind all events relate to it to improve performance?
3. Can some fields won't be rendered until they are scrolled into the window?
4. Suggest there is a block inside a polymer-element: `<div id = 'container'></div>`, and content inside it will be generated by user's interaction. When I set `this.$.container.innerHTML = '<some-other-polymer-element></some-other-polymer-element>'`, I got a warning: "bind prior to ....", and it renders slowly, but using `<template repeat>` will attach too many events, what's the better way?

Many thanks~~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `<template if="...">` is slower because it needs to remove/add nodes but if you have big parts of the DOM you show hide and you don't do this often it might be advantageous because the DOM becomes smaller.

2) You can use one-time binding `[[ ... ]]` instead of `{{...}}`

3) You have to code this yourself `<template if="...">` or similar

4) it depends/not enough information